# cordova-plugin-firebase unregister to push notification

Tags: android, jquery, ios, cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using the cordova-plugin-firebase plugin to receive push notifications from firebase to my iOS and Android devices.

What I want is, that the user can disable or enable the push notificications through the app.

Everything works fine, except for the unregister part.

I am using the `window.FirebasePlugin.unregister();` function. 
After that, my iOS devices won't receive messages anymore, which is good.
But after trying to register again, with the    `window.FirebasePlugin.getToken();` function, my iOS device still won't get any messages.

So on iOS I can't register again. On Android however, the unregister function won't work at all. I still get all notifications send from firebase.

What am I doing wrong ? How can I register and unregister?